# Can I get user ID from Google Play Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-play

I start to learning Flutter.
Is there any way that we can get a Google Play ID from user when utilizing Google Play Services?

Answer (score 0):

1)Retrieve the email and password linked with google play services on firebase


2)Or rather sign in with play account by enabling Play Games authentication in Firebase authentication and for further implementation :

=> follow the steps in https://pub.dev/packages/play_games